# Using Python to create a right triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm confused and frustrated as to why my program is not executing the way it should. I am trying to create a right triangle using asterisks on python ver 3. I am using the exact code from the text book and it comes out as a straight line. Please enlighten me.

example

```
size = 7

for row in range (size):
    for col in range (row + 1):
        print('*', end='')
        print()
```

results in

```
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
```

all in one column

Answer (score 7):

In Python, indentation counts. The final `print` should be aligned with the second `for`.

```
size = 7

for row in range (size):
    for col in range (row + 1):
        print('*', end='')
    print()
```

Result:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
```

An empty `print` function effectively means "move to a new line". if both `print` statements occur at the same indentation level, then every time you print an asterisk, you'll move to the next line. If the second `print` goes *outside* the inner `for` loop, you'll only get 7 newlines.

Comment: wow thank you I've been working on this same problem for like an hour and a half now.

Answer (score 1):

as an alternative you can use one `for` loop !

```
>>> s=''
>>> for i in range(7):
...  s+='*'
...  print (s)
... 
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
```

Comment: Yes, although that `print` needs parentheses, if we're working in Python 3.X.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the most readable solution but if you fancy oneliners this is one way of doing it:

```
print "\n".join(["".join(["*" for col in range(row+1)]) for row in range(7)])
```

**EDIT**

Just to make it even shorter:

```
print "\n".join(["*" * (row+1) for row in range(7)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = 'x '
str2 = ' ' #give space within the inverted comma
for i in range (1,6):
    print((str2 * (5 - i)) + (str1 * i))
    #print((str1 * i)+(str2 * (5 - i)))
```

other program:

```
str1 = 'x '
str2 = '' #give empty string(remove sace from the single inverted comma)
for i in range (1,6):
    print((str2 * (5 - i)) + (str1 * i))
    #print((str1 * i)+(str2 * (5 - i)))
```